# Not able to save the file in custom path directory using Python Telegram bot

Tags: python, api, telegram

I'm downloading files using the Telegram bot, and my current code looks like this:

```
def file_handler(Update, context: CallbackContext):
    file = context.bot.getFile(Update.message.document.file_id)
    print("file_id: " + str(Update.message.document.file_id))
    file.download(custom_path='C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/files')

def main():
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document, file_handler))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And when I do this:

```
file.download()
```

It downloads the file in the current directory, but I want to download all the files in the folder. So I looked up the documentation here: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.file.html, and indeed I can set custom path to download the files in that folder. However, when I use my current code, I get a permission error:

```
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fobj:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/files'
```

And I'm not sure why. I tried re-creating the folder and re-start the program, but I always get the same error. I looked for this specific error in the Telegram bot, but nothing shows up. Can you please help?

Comment: You can't write to a folder, `C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/files` is a folder, not a file.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, so in this case, I just keep overwriting to the file?

Comment: Try something like: `file.download(custom_path='C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/files/file1.txt')`

Comment: Can you leave it as answer so I can select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

You cannot treat a folder as a file, the [`download`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.file.html#telegram.File.download) method take a path to a file. As mentioned in the documentation:

> Download this file. By default, **the file** is saved in the current working directory with its original filename as reported by Telegram. If the file has no filename, it the file ID will be used as filename. If a `custom_path` is supplied, it will be saved to that path instead. If out is defined, the file contents will be saved to that object using the `out.write` method.

### Code

#### Change in Code

You can use change the following code:

```
custom_path='C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/files'
```

to

```
custom_path='C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/files/file1.txt'
```

#### Full code

```
def file_handler(Update, context: CallbackContext):
    file = context.bot.getFile(Update.message.document.file_id)
    print("file_id: " + str(Update.message.document.file_id))
    file.download(custom_path='C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/Telegram-Database/files/file1.txt')

def main():
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document, file_handler))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```